# Erro ao redirecionar paginas internas com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, menu

Boa noite.
A minha duvida é a seguinte, tenho um menu e nele varias opçoes criei uma VIEW chamada consultaProdutos e gostaria de que ao clicar em consulta o mesmo fosse para essa tela, porem isso nao ocorre, como redirecionar paginas utilizando o codeigniter uma vez que o mesmo utiliza MVC, abaixo segue imagem de como esta a estrutura.[image: menu]

Exemplo de como esta o menu atualmente..
Obs: ja tentei utilizar o base_url porem sem exito.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 `<li><a href="consultaProdutos.php">Consulta</a></li>`
 '</ul>'
```

Comment: Mas você montou o controller pra chamar ele?

Answer (score 1):

Você não deve acessar a view consultaProdutos.php diretamente embora seja possível, mas não é assim que funciona em MVC e no caso no CodeIgniter também.

Idealmente no arquivo de view `consultaProdutos.php` devia haver a seguinte instrução para negar o acesso direto:

```
defined("BASEPATH") or exit("Acesso direto negado");
```

Você deve criar primeiro um Controller para produtos, depois criar uma função para carregar essa view.

```
class Produto extends CI_Controller {
   public function consultaProdutos(){
     // consultaProdutos abaixo é o nome da view
     $this->load->view("consultaProdutos");
   }
}
```

Seu link vai ficar assim utilizado o URL Helper:

```
<a href="<?=site_url("produtos/consultaProdutos") ?>">Consulta</a>
```

A parte `produtos` indica o Controller, e a parte `consultaProdutos` indica o nome da ação.

Para carregar esse helper utilize o código abaixo ou configure ele para carregar automático no autoload.php:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Você também poderia utilizar o seguinte link(menos recomendado)

```
<a href="index.php/produto/consultaProdutos">Consulta</a>
```